# What is the Google Analytics client prefix?

Tags: google-analytics

So we can track conversions on a hotel booking widget on our website we are asked to provide the Google Analytics client prefix. They say: Your Google Analytics client prefix - Usually, the name of your property in lower case with dashes replacing any spaces, e.g. Sydney hotels would be sydney-hotels.

Anybody know where to find the Your Google Analytics client prefix?
I have searched online but couldn't find out how to do this :/

Thank You for your help!

Comment: AFAIK there is not such thing in Google Analytics, like client prefix. What would be the purpose of this data or identifier? Do you need to identify the Google Analytics property, or the hotel property?

Comment: @kgrg I didn't think that there was such thing. So maybe it really is just the hotel property, as they are stating: Usually the name of your property in lower case with dashes replacing any spaces.

Comment: Sorry, but in this case this question has really nothing to do with Google Analytics, and it's hard to tell without any context, what is the variable that you are looking for.

Comment: The provider says: To enable the advanced tracking in Google Analytics, you must first request support to update your account.

Contact support to ask that advanced tracking with source attribution be set up for your hotel. You should include the following information:

Your Google Analytics Account ID, (e.g. UA-123456-1) and the type of tracking code you are using on your site (e.g. classic or universal)
Your Google Analytics client prefix. Usually, the name of your property in lower case with dashes replacing any spaces

Thats all they share, they say that they cant offer more support

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related. may be better suited for.   https://webapps.stackexchange.com/